# empty pdf file with lyluatex

Tags: lilypond

I have tested lyluatex to produce some parts of music. But I get an empty pdf file. Any advice ?
Config system : windows 8.1 64 bits MiKTeX2.9. last update :07/10/2019

```
\RequirePackage[log]{snapshot}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage{xparse}         
\usepackage{xpatch}         


\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage[program={C:/Program Files (x86)/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe}]{lyluatex}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tune}{}{\ly}{\endly}
\begin{document}

\section{Lilypond with \LaTeX}

Some text to describe \emph{lilypond} environment.

\begin{lilypond}
music = \relative {
c d e
}
\score {
\new ChoirStaff \with {instrumentName = "2 Fl."}
 <<
\new Staff \transpose c c' \music
\new Staff {
\clef bass
\music
}
>>
}
\end{lilypond}



\begin{lilypond}
\version "2.19.83"
\relative c' {
\omit Staff.TimeSignature
c1 \break
d1 \break
e1 \break
f1 \break
g1 \break
a1 \break
b1 \break
c1 \break
}
\end{lilypond}


\begin{lilypond}
\version "2.19.83"
mel = {
    \set Staff.instrumentName = "First violin"
    \tempo \markup \typewriter Allegro
    c' d' e' f'
    g' a' b' c''
    \mark \markup \sans "Sans Mark"
}
lyr = \lyricmode {
    do re mi fa so -- la si -- do
}

\score {
    <<
    \new Staff \new Voice = "mel" \mel
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "mel" \lyr
    >>
}
\end{lilypond}



\end{document}
```

This my log file :

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2019.1.13)  7 OCT 2019 20:51
 restricted system commands enabled.
**lylua-test.tex  lualatex   --shell -escape
(./lylua-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-08-11 2.67 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-08-11 2.67 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/Haouam/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2019-08-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2
019-08-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.109”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/Haouam/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2019-09-13 3.00 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 1.014 seconds
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/snapshot/snapshot.sty"
Package: snapshot 2012/08/06 v2.13
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/Haouam/AppData/Local/
MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 225.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def"
File: luatex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2019-10-02 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2019-10-02 L3 programming layer (code)
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable5
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count93
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count94
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count95
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count96
\c_log_iow=\count97
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count98
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count99
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count100
\l__iow_indent_int=\count101
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count102
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count103
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen109
\g__intarray_font_int=\count104
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count112
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count113
\g__fp_array_int=\count114
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count115
\l__sort_length_int=\count116
\l__sort_min_int=\count117
\l__sort_top_int=\count118
\l__sort_max_int=\count119
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count120
\l__sort_block_int=\count121
\l__sort_begin_int=\count122
\l__sort_end_int=\count123
\l__sort_A_int=\count124
\l__sort_B_int=\count125
\l__sort_C_int=\count126
\l__str_internal_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count128
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count129
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count130
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count131
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count132
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count133
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count134
\l__regex_balance_int=\count135
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count136
\l__regex_mode_int=\count137
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count138
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count139
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count140
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count141
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count142
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count143
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count144
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count145
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count146
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count148
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count149
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count150
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count151
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count154
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count155
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count156
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count157
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count158
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count159
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count160
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count161
\l__regex_step_int=\count162
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count163
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count164
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count165
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count166
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count167
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count168
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count169
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count170
\c_empty_box=\box27
\l_tmpa_box=\box28
\l_tmpb_box=\box29
\g_tmpa_box=\box30
\g_tmpb_box=\box31
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen124
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen131
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen134
\g__char_data_ior=\read1

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def"
File: l3deprecation.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2019-04-06 v L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count171
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
Package: xparse 2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count172
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count173
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count174
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count175
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xpatch/xpatch.sty"
Package: xpatch 2012/10/02 v0.3 Extending etoolbox patching commands

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count176
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty"
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty"
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count177
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable6
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable7
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/lualatex/lyluatex/lyluatex.sty"
Package: lyluatex 2019/05/27 v1.0f

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count178
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/07/20 v1.3b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 105.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen135
\Gin@req@width=\dimen136
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/minibox/minibox.sty"
Package: minibox 2013/06/21 v0.2a Another type of box.
\l_minibox_rule_dim=\dimen137
\l_minibox_pad_dim=\dimen138
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty"
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty"
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks16
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty"
Package: currfile 2015/04/23 v0.7c Provides the file path elements of the curren
t input file

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
))))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty"
Package: filehook 2019/10/03 v0.6 Hooks for input files
)
\c@currfiledepth=\count179
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty"
Package: pdfpages 2019/09/21 v0.5n Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty"
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count180
\calc@Bcount=\count181
\calc@Adimen=\dimen139
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen140
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count182
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty"
Package: eso-pic 2018/04/12 v2.0h eso-pic (RN)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty"
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)))
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen141
\AM@pageheight=\dimen142

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppluatex.def"
File: ppluatex.def 2019/09/21 v0.5n Pdfpages driver for LuaTeX (AM)
)
\AM@pagebox=\box46
\AM@global@opts=\toks17
\AM@toc@title=\toks18
\c@AM@survey=\count183
\AM@templatesizebox=\box47
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty"
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box48
\sift@deathcycles=\count184
\@vwid@loff=\dimen143
\@vwid@roff=\dimen144
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty"
Package: metalogo 2010/05/29 v0.12 Extended TeX logo macros

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\xl@everylogo=\toks19
\xl@@everylogo=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \TeX on input line 193.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeX on input line 202.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeXe on input line 219.
)
Lua module: lyluatex-options 2019/05/27 1.0f Module lyluatex-options.
Lua module: lyluatex-lib 2019/05/27 1.0f Module lyluatex-lib.
Lua module: lyluatex 2018/03/12 1.0b Module lyluatex.[\directlua]:1: attempt to 
call a nil value (field 'make_list_file')
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.140 }

? 
) (./lylua-test.aux)
\openout1 = lylua-test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count185
\scratchdimen=\dimen145
\scratchbox=\box49
\nofMPsegments=\count186
\nofMParguments=\count187
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count188
\MPscratchDim=\dimen146
\MPnumerator=\count189
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count190
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)

Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks23
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 43
8.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG
,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box50

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/pdflscape.sty"
Package: pdflscape 2016/05/14 v0.11 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty"
Package: lscape 2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
Package pdflscape Info: Auto-detected driver: pdftex on input line 81.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <17.28> on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 18.
Inserting `readline' at position 1 in `process_input_buffer'.
Removing  `readline' from `process_input_buffer'.C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex
/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1395: attempt to concatenate a nil value (field 'sf
family')
stack traceback:
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1395: in function '
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua.set_fonts'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@currentfonts ..., \sffamilyid , \ttfamilyid )}
                                                  \endgroup 
l.36 \end{lilypond}

? 
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1083: attempt to con
catenate a nil value (field 'tmpdir')
stack traceback:
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1083: in method 'ou
tput_filename'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:531: in method 'cal
c_properties'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1088: in method 'pr
ocess'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}

l.36 \end{lilypond}

? 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 36--37

 []

Inserting `readline' at position 1 in `process_input_buffer'.
Removing  `readline' from `process_input_buffer'.C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex
/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1395: attempt to concatenate a nil value (field 'sf
family')
stack traceback:
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1395: in function '
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua.set_fonts'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@currentfonts ..., \sffamilyid , \ttfamilyid )}
                                                  \endgroup 
l.53 \end{lilypond}

? 
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1083: attempt to con
catenate a nil value (field 'tmpdir')
stack traceback:
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1083: in method 'ou
tput_filename'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:531: in method 'cal
c_properties'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1088: in method 'pr
ocess'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}

l.53 \end{lilypond}

? 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 53--54

 []

Inserting `readline' at position 1 in `process_input_buffer'.
Removing  `readline' from `process_input_buffer'.C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex
/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1395: attempt to concatenate a nil value (field 'sf
family')
stack traceback:
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1395: in function '
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua.set_fonts'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@currentfonts ..., \sffamilyid , \ttfamilyid )}
                                                  \endgroup 
l.75 \end{lilypond}

? 
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1083: attempt to con
catenate a nil value (field 'tmpdir')
stack traceback:
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1083: in method 'ou
tput_filename'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:531: in method 'cal
c_properties'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/lyluatex.lua:1088: in method 'pr
ocess'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}

l.75 \end{lilypond}

? 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 75--76

 []

[1

{C:/Users/Haouam/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(./lylua-test.aux)
\RequireVersions{
  *{application}{eTeX}    {0000/00/00 v2.2}
  *{format} {LaTeX2e}     {2018-12-01 v2.e}
  *{package}{snapshot}    {2012/08/06 v2.13}
  *{class}  {article}     {2019/08/27 v1.4j}
  *{file}   {size12.clo}  {2019/08/27 v1.4j}
  *{package}{xcolor}      {2016/05/11 v2.12}
  *{file}   {color.cfg}   {2016/01/02 v1.6}
  *{file}   {luatex.def}  {2018/01/08 v1.0l}
  *{package}{xparse}      {2019-05-28 v3}
  *{package}{expl3}       {2019-10-02 v3}
  *{file}   {expl3-code.tex}{2019-10-02 v3}
  *{file}   {l3deprecation.def}{2019-04-06 v3}
  *{file}   {l3backend-pdfmode.def}{2019-04-06 v3}
  *{package}{xpatch}      {2012/10/02 v0.3}
  *{package}{etoolbox}    {2019/09/21 v2.5h}
  *{package}{luatexbase}  {2015/10/04 v1.3}
  *{package}{ctablestack} {2015/10/01 v1.0}
  *{package}{lyluatex}    {2019/05/27 v1.0f}
  *{package}{xkeyval}     {2014/12/03 v2.7a}
  *{file}   {xkeyval.tex} {2014/12/03 v2.7a}
  *{package}{graphicx}    {2017/06/01 v1.1a}
  *{package}{graphics}    {2019/07/20 v1.3b}
  *{package}{trig}        {2016/01/03 v1.10}
  *{file}   {graphics.cfg}{2016/06/04 v1.11}
  *{package}{minibox}     {2013/06/21 v0.2a}
  *{package}{environ}     {2014/05/04 v0.3}
  *{package}{trimspaces}  {2009/09/17 v1.1}
  *{package}{currfile}    {2015/04/23 v0.7c}
  *{package}{kvoptions}   {2016/05/16 v3.12}
  *{package}{ltxcmds}     {2016/05/16 v1.23}
  *{package}{kvsetkeys}   {2016/05/16 v1.17}
  *{package}{infwarerr}   {2016/05/16 v1.4}
  *{package}{etexcmds}    {2016/05/16 v1.6}
  *{package}{ifluatex}    {2016/05/16 v1.4}
  *{package}{filehook}    {2019/10/03 v0.6}
  *{package}{pdfpages}    {2019/09/21 v0.5n}
  *{package}{ifthen}      {2014/09/29 v1.1c}
  *{package}{calc}        {2017/05/25 v4.3}
  *{package}{eso-pic}     {2018/04/12 v2.0h}
  *{package}{atbegshi}    {2016/06/09 v1.18}
  *{package}{ifpdf}       {2018/09/07 v3.3}
  *{file}   {ppluatex.def}{2019/09/21 v0.5n}
  *{package}{varwidth}    {2009/03/30 v0.92;}
  *{package}{metalogo}    {2010/05/29 v0.12}
  *{package}{ifxetex}     {2010/09/12 v0.6}
  *{-------}{Document-specific files:}{----}
  *{file}   {supp-pdf.mkii}{0000/00/00 v0.0}
  *{package}{epstopdf-base}{2016/05/15 v2.6}
  *{package}{grfext}      {2016/05/16 v1.2}
  *{package}{kvdefinekeys}{2016/05/16 v1.4}
  *{package}{pdftexcmds}  {2019/07/25 v0.30}
  *{package}{pdflscape}   {2016/05/14 v0.11}
  *{package}{lscape}      {2000/10/22 v3.01}
}
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 14023 strings out of 494300
 125171,319454 words of node,token memory allocated
 415 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 49 glue_spec,
 5 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:86,3:17,4:6,5:41,6:8,7:130,9:44,11:5
 17957 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 41 fonts using 6956599 bytes
 47i,6n,61p,1639b,436s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<c:/program files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-italic.otf><c:/p
rogram files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.otf><c:/progr
am files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-bold.otf>
Output written on lylua-test.pdf (1 page, 11461 bytes).

PDF statistics: 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: I don't have lilypond installed to test, but your pathes looks curious. On my system lyluatex.lua is not in tex\latex.

Comment: Honestly I don't know ! that's what I have in my distribution. What do you suggest ?

Comment: check if you have another lyluatex.lua in scripts.

Comment: In scripts I have lyluatex.lua

Comment: Try what happens if you move the `MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/lyluatex/` folder somewhere else.

Comment: the folder with lyluatex.sty ? or just lyluatex.lua.

Comment: I don't know what you have in this folder. Whatever is in it, move it away.

Comment: In this folder I have lyluatex.sty and lyluatex.lua. I moved the folder in my Desktop.

Comment: A damn. I forget this. Don't move the sty away.

Comment: I moved just lyluatex.lua, refresh database, compile. I get the same result

Comment: I installed now lilypond and tried. I had to remove the \version declarations as I installed the stable version, but beside this it compiles fine. Comparing the log it is clear that you have a much older lyluatex module: Lua module: lyluatex 2018/03/12 1.0b Module lyluatex, my version is 2019/05/27 1.0f.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in lyluatex with MikTeX; [it’s fixed](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/pull/300) as soon as you’re using LilyPond <= 2.22 (there is a [bug](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/issues/301) with 2.24).